# What is it about this Answer that qualifies it as being low quality?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I'm getting irritated with the review system.  It seems inconsistent at best.  Review feedback is even worse, completely unintuitive.

I've been hit by [this review audit](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/220066) before.  I gave the same answer as I did last time so I could take a screenshot of it.  I still don't see why it qualifies for being removed.

[image: review audit]

Is it because it's short?  I don't think every answer needs to be several paragraphs long with lots of special formatting.

There is another similar answer, but this one provides instructions for verifying the version of the software installed, so it has something a little different.

Call me naive or whatever you will, but if I'm going to be blind audited and told that my feedback is wrong I'd like to exactly know why.  It's not enough just to be told I'm doing it wrong.

This system is extremely frustrating, I'm reaching a point where I no longer wish to contribute.

Answer (score 13):

You would not be the first to complain about this kind of thing.  Even a cursory glance through the review-audits tag would yield dozens of similar complaints, were they properly tagged.  But, see here: [Should we game the audit system?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6514/should-we-game-the-audit-system)

Fortunately, failing one or two of these has no consequence.

Unfortunately, they are a total waste of your time, and very discouraging when they make no sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's not because it's short, it's because it doesn't answer the question, except in the most trivial sense (the closest thing to a question in there is "I have no idea what to do next").  Since it doesn't answer the question, it got turned into a comment.

Comment: The second sentence looks like an attempted answer? Tbh this looks more like someone who didn't have the rep to comment, wanted to add info (the php -v) and decided to put it in an answer not entirely understanding the system. Which makes for bad UX and a bad audit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the answer isn't clear on what basis the it is trying to get the questioner to check the PHP version. It's pretty clear upon further thought that the answer is telling the questioner that "maybe you don't have the PHP version you need; why don't you check it and do this if you don't have the correct version."

While that certainly answers the question IMO, the immediate lack of clarity is what I think elicited the downvote reaction. And the downvoter indeed can be faulted to not comment on it, or even edit the answer to spell out the what's eventually is pretty obvious.